# ExpressionParser without double quotes in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, spring, string

Using spring framework ExpressionParser to execute the string expression.

Now using this code I can parse the inputString expression.
But my requirement is inputString should not contain double-quotes for replace function parameter.
e.g inputString shuold be "#{replace(ABCD,AB, PQ)}";
So with this replace method do not support and throws exception
Property or field 'ABCD' cannot be found on object of type

So how to make this replace method or expression works for ExpressionParser with string input without quotes to the function?

```
private void parserTest() {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/54694322
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        String inputString="#{replace(ABCD,\"AB\", \"PQ\")}";
        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(inputString, new TemplateParserContext());
        String outputString = (String) exp.getValue(new StandardEvaluationContext(this));

    }

// replace function
    public String replace(String srcString, String regex, String replacement) {
            return srcString.replaceFirst(regex, replacement);
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, can you elaborate on what the issue is?  Also, please read our [ask] page for more hints on how to improve this question

Comment: Is the issue as simple as making the `inputString="#{replace('ABCD','AB','PQ')}";` ?

Comment: @ochi No my expression input string should be like "#{replace(ABCD,AB, PQ)}" So input to the replace methods expect value in " " quote like "ABCD", not ABCD or AB or PQ and my input string do not contain " "[double quotes] to the string so its giving error